# How to determine selected gridview item?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a gridView. instead of ItemTemplate I used user control for gridviewitems because I cant manage to trigger the button click event in the itemtemplate

here is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count(); i++)
{
     GridViewItem gridViewItem = new GridViewItem();
     gridViewItem.Tag = i;
     PhotoItem item = new PhotoItem();

     item.photoTitleTextBlock.Text = collection[i].Type.ToString();
     item.eraseButton.Click += (sender, args) => { itemSent(item); };

     gridViewItem.Content = item;
     gvIdTypes.Items.Add(gridViewItem);
}
```

in my userControl PhotoItem there are textblock, button and image textblock.text comes from collection 
if gridview item is selected(via `gridView.selectionChanged` event) web cam takes photo and puts on the image of the UserControl

how can I figure out which of the item is selected in the selectionChanged event

Comment: How about getting the value of the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property of the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ItemClick` instead and then you can access the `ClickedItem` in `ItemClickEventArgs`